# DCM page in Filestream_Data_Filegroup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, database-internals, filestream

I'm doing some research about the DCM (Differential Change Map) page in SQL Server 2016.
This is what I discovered so far:

- page type: 16
- each DCM page covers a GAM interval
- each data file has a DCM page starting with page_id 6

When I analyzed a database containing filestream data I discovered something strange. I used following query to retrieve the file_id of the file containing the filestream data:

```
select file_id from sys.database_files where type_desc='FILESTREAM'
```

Next I used `DBCC Page` to analyze the DCM page of this file

```
dbcc traceon(3604,1)
dbcc page(33,65537,6,3)
dbcc traceoff(3604,1)
```

In the 'Allocation Status' I saw that the DIFF pointed to (1:6).

> Allocation Status
>
> GAM (1:2) = ALLOCATED                
>   SGAM (1:3) = NOT ALLOCATED
>   PFS (1:1) = 0x44 ALLOCATED 100_PCT_FULL 
>   DIFF (1:6) = CHANGED
>   ML (1:7) = NOT MIN_LOGGED

Does this mean that a file with FILESTREAM data always points to a DCM page in data file containing the filestream table?
I think this is because a file with FILESTREAM data doesn't contains data pages but serves as a container for the files.
Is my conclusion correct?

Comment: I'm confused by the phrase " the file containing the filestream data". That "file" isn't a file, it is a folder. I.e., that folder contains files (one file for each instance of BLOB data, where one instance is a value, like a column value for a row).

Comment: @tibor karaszi: I refer to this as a file because it has a file_id and it also appears in sys.database_files. That's actually my question, is this the reason why the DCM file points to the data file because it is actually a container/directory?